# Cannot get into GUI after trying to set up radeon graphics

Tags: xubuntu, radeon

I'm using an laptop running XUbuntu 16.04. I added `radeon.modeset=1 i915.modeset=1 radeon.runpm=0` to grub default command line and now all I see is a crash message which contains `radeon_crtc_set_config` in the crash log. 
[image: The crash I see]

Comment: If you can open a TTY (CTRL+ALT+F1..F6) you should be able to undo.

Comment: Thank you for help @CelticWarrior . I was able to remove the problematic entry from grub(`radeon.runpm=0`) from grub and use it as normal.